# Как сделать что-то вроде ссылки наверху на github?

Tags: github

Я только начинаю разбираться в github-е, создал репозиторий, назвал его. На некоторых репозиториях видел что-то вроде ссылки наверху.
[image: картинка]

Как это сделать?

Comment: Там рядом с этом местом должна быть кнопочка для редактирования описания.

Answer (score 1):

Шестеренка в красном кружке, там как раз сможете отредактировать описание, добавить ссылку и т.д.

[image: Шестеренка]